# How to Release Memory used by Silverlight Controls on closing form

Tags: silverlight, memory-management

I have a silverlight application in that when a form is opened it is using nearly 17mb but when i close the form it is releasing any memory . i am disposing all the variables and objects but GC is not releasing any thing . i also removed all the controls at runtime when closing form.
when i verified with ANTS Memory profiler . there it is showing as NativeObjectSafeHandle   196440  which is largest one that can be disposed  and second largest is UnmanagedMemoryStream  .

In memory profiler it is showing lot of silverlight internal references that iam not able to dispose them like styles, system.windows.controls and resources . Even though iam clearing form.resources.clear().

Pls suggest me in releasing the memory .

Thanks
krishna

Comment: how do you call GC.SuppressFinalize?? is any unmanaged are you calling dispose pattern correct? resources used? NativeObjectSafeHandle is .NET Framework stuff inside Microsoft.Internal Namespace which is which you don't have to worry  GC handles it. 

More over look at this for more info regarding analyzing memory in silverlight http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slperf/archive/2010/08/19/analyzing-silverlight-memory-usage-part-1-obtaining-measurements.aspx

Comment: Yea ..i have called GC.SuppressFinalize.  We have a Memory Leak issue. on opening form it is using nearly 15 MB and after closing it is releasing around 5 to 7 Mb . i had disposed all the objects in Dispose method.
Is it possible to release total memory which it is used in Loading of Form about 15 Mb. ??
If it is not releasing total memory does it means still we have memory leak in application ??

Comment: You almost never have to worry about the deallocation of managed memory in .NET since CLR take care of these stuff. Garbage collector collects these objects when he wants. The Finalizer is only needed for unmanaged resources. in another words you don't have to worry about those that aren't released since CLR wil take care of this.

I think following videos explain this process better


(Jump to 0.45 in the video)

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MEVeurJtiW8 


http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cV8YJqc37ww

Comment: Another link 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the Reply !!!!

I verified in using TaskManager when closing form it is not releasing total memory . one of our clients are complaining memory leak issue memory in Task Manager is growing up. when closing form it releases some amount of memory not total used memory . Can You suggest me how to explain them in proper way ??

Before it was not disposed objects properly now i disposed objects in Dispose method and it releasing some amount memory.
When i verified in ANTS memory profiler tool.showing 100 kb objects are not disposed .But clients are complaining that it is not total memory

Comment: @Krishna I am facing the same kind of issue. How did you solve the issue? Do you have suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to not force a garbage collection in most cases. Since CLR knows best way to handle it. But if you really wanna force garbage collection try GC.Collect this will force immediate garbage collection of all generations

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357(v=vs.110).aspx

Also please refer to the links i provided in comments for better explanation.

Comment: How can we identify memory is released from form when closing form ??
Can we see in TaskManager ???

Comment: Use memory profiler like ants or CLRMemory profiler. its described in that video i sent.

Comment: i Used Memory profiler i disposed all the variables and controls which can be disposed but there are some objects in NativeObjectsSafeHandle in that all the internal .net references like system.windows.controls references are present . Can we dispose .net references or is there any way to rid of objects in NativeObjectSafeHandle ???